# Future tense - I would be available anytime until 12pm or after 8pm from 2nd of April

Tags: future-tense, time, future-time, time-reference

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I will be available anytime until 12pm or after 8pm from 2nd of April.

or

> I am available anytime until 12pm or after 8pm from 2nd of April.

Comment: English does not have a future tense. Instead, we have a number ways of referring to future time. One of them is the use of the modal auxiliary verb "will". as in your first example, and another is the present tense of "be", as in your second example. A further way is the idiomatic "be going", as in "I am going to be available anytime ..."

Comment: English certainly *does* have future tenses. In fact, there are four of them: Simple Future ("I will run"), Future Perfect ("I will have run"), Future Progressive ("I will be running"), and Future Perfect-Progressive ("I will have been running").

Comment: @JasonBassford To us lower mortals it does and for practical purposes, but not in the higher realms inhabited by some linguists.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks to my exposure to this site, I've come to realize that there are different contexts for terminology. Blanket statements are often inadvisable; they should either be avoided or qualified. It's confusion over the framework used that often leads to unnecessary debate. (In hindsight, I would have phrased my earlier comment differently—although, currently, I probably wouldn't have commented at all...)

Comment: @JasonBassford You are preaching to the choir. However, I am not the choirmaster (mistress?) and am merely informing you of this. Just so you know...

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.

In distinguishing between them, You would "typically" use the first example for a single event, and the second example for a recurring series of events.

For instance, if you want to schedule a meeting with your boss to discuss something specific, you would use the future tense. ("I **will** be free . . .")

On the other hand, if you are a professor who has posted weekly hours, you would use the present tense. ("My hours **are** . . .")

However, there is no rule that says you have to use one or the other. It's just a matter of convention and preference.